# Assign each element’s value with a class from an object based on ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I have this object:

```js
const person = {
    "name": "john",
    "address": "john’s home"
  };
```

and this part of a form:

```html
<input class="form-control john" id="name">
<input class="form-control john" id="address">
```

then how do I assign the value of each `id` with its associated value from the object?

Something like:

```js
$(".john").each(function(){
  $(id).val(person.id)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Set value of input using **[`$(this).val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)** or `this.value = value`.
2. Get object value using its `id`. You can get the ID using `this.id`.

Code:

```js
var person = {
  "name": "john",
  "address": "john's home"
};
$('.john').each(function() {
  $(this).val(person[this.id]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control john" id="name">
<input class="form-control john" id="address">
```

Also you can iterate over them using **[`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)** with a callback:

```js
var person = {
  "name": "john",
  "address": "john's home"
};
$('.john').val(function() {
  return person[this.id];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control john" id="name">
<input class="form-control john" id="address">
```

Reference: **[Accessing object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**